# Weird sort behaviour when using custom sort filter on ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, ng-options

I'm having issues using my custom sort filter together with ng-options on a select element. The problem is that it doesn't sort my numeric value as it should.

You can see the issue in the plnkr below, it should sort on the 'id' value, but the sorting in the select element is very strange.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Z99aEFLuWUFWuyc8GM9t?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.filter('sortKeyIds', function() {
    return function(input) {
      
        //Copy original list
        var keys = input.concat([]);
        
        keys.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.id - b.id;
        });
        
        return keys;
    }
});

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.controllerName = "MainController";
    $scope.months = [
      {"id":15,"val":"15x250"},
      {"id":88,"val":"88x31"},
      {"id":120,"val":"120x90"},
      {"id":125,"val":"125x125"},
      {"id":160,"val":"160x600"},
      {"id":180,"val":"180x150"},
      {"id":234,"val":"234x60"},
      {"id":240,"val":"240x400"},
      {"id":250,"val":"250x250"},
      {"id":300,"val":"300x100"},
      {"id":336,"val":"336x280"},
      {"id":468,"val":"468x60"},
      {"id":720,"val":"720x300"},
      {"id":728,"val":"728x90"},
      {"id":980,"val":"980x300"},
      {"id":1250,"val":"1250x250"}
      ];
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularCameraApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h3>Weird sorting</h3>
    <select ng-model="avtripExpMonth" ng-options="value.lang as value.val for (key, value) in months | sortKeyIds"></select>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please put the full code to replicate and see the problem **in** the question, not just linked. Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) allow you to do runnable examples right here on-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

/* You could remove this part.
app.filter('sortKeyIds', function() {
    return function(input) {
      
        //Copy original list
        var keys = input.concat([]);
        console.log(keys);
        keys.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.id - b.id;
        });
        
        return keys;
    }
});*/

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.controllerName = "MainController";
    $scope.months = [
      {"id":15,"val":"15x250"},
      {"id":88,"val":"88x31"},
      {"id":120,"val":"120x90"},
      {"id":125,"val":"125x125"},
      {"id":160,"val":"160x600"},
      {"id":180,"val":"180x150"},
      {"id":234,"val":"234x60"},
      {"id":240,"val":"240x400"},
      {"id":250,"val":"250x250"},
      {"id":300,"val":"300x100"},
      {"id":336,"val":"336x280"},
      {"id":468,"val":"468x60"},
      {"id":720,"val":"720x300"},
      {"id":728,"val":"728x90"},
      {"id":980,"val":"980x300"},
      {"id":1250,"val":"1250x250"}
      ];
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.one {
  font-size:2em;
}
.two {
  color:red;
}
.aclass {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularCameraApp</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <h3>Weird sorting</h3>
    <select ng-model="avtripExpMonth" ng-options="month.val for month in months track by month.id | orderBy:month.id"></select>
    <ul id="preview"></ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

you could use the orderBy filter by Angular. not sure why you want to use a custom filter for a trivial task.

does **[this fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wJG1WXKtl4j1O33OMck?p=preview)** work for you. i didn't really understand your `(key, value)`. this is how i'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't weird. You are not using the right syntax. Angular broke on that filter.

You do not need `(key, value)` on ng-options. And filter syntax is correct.

Here is the updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NOztGl4PZpHdwfFbXVwZ?p=preview)

```
<select ng-model="avtripExpMonth" ng-options="value.lang as value.val for value in months | sortKeyIds"></select>
```

I've just changed it to `value` and everything works fine.

Hope it helps